# ER721Token contract functions all working in remix, but not in geth --dev console with web3 commands?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, remix

I'm using the following contract with all the dependencies.

[MasteringEthereum/code/auction_dapp/backend/contracts/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol](https://github.com/conwise18/MasteringEthereum/blob/develop/code/auction_dapp/backend/contracts/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol)

When deployed in remix the contract functions work fine, all of them execute and the data is stored in the correct places (i.e arrays and mappings) Although when I deploy to a local `geth --dev` console the following functions execute but the state of the contract does not change

```
erc721token.mint(acct1, 9000 {from: acct1})

erc721token.totalSupply()

erc721token.tokenByIndex([0])

erc721token.balanceOf(acct1)

erc721token.exists(9000) 

erc721token.ownerOf(9000)
```

???

Any help would be fantastic.

Comment: Did you check the transaction receipt to verify the execution status? Remix does calculate the transaction gas estimation, but geth console does not and it will use a default gas that might not be enough to execute the transaction. Try setting an explicit gas limit `{ gas: 1000000, from: acc1 }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ismael. The problem is fixed with your suggestion.

Problem was

erc721token.mint(acct1, 9000 {from: acct1})

transaction was not minting a new token, even though a transaction was mined.

gasUsed: 100000,

deedrepository.mint(eth.accounts[0], 1000,  {gas: 1000000, from: eth.accounts[0]})

gasUsed: 157938,

calling the same function with a higher gas limit as a transaction parameter solved to problem because the function needs a higher gas price for the computation be run complete by the EVM.

NOTE: 
"0x0" in transaction receipt indicates transaction failure.
"0x1" in transaction receipt in transaction success.

Comment: For people who come across this answer, I think you mean "higher gas limit" rather than "higher gas price".